# Should multiple applications be run on one Pi 3 or multiple Pi 3's?

Tags: pi-3, networking

Recently I've considered hosting applications on my own machines at home. I'm planning to host the following on Raspberry Pi 3's:

- My personal website (uses Node.js)
- Blog using an installation of [Ghost](https://ghost.org), which also uses Node.js and uses a MySQL database
- A MySQL database, for the blog

All the websites will be put behind a Cloudflare proxy, so I don't think speed will be an issue. Would one Pi 3 suffice? Or will the three applications need to be put on separate Pi's?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is going to depend on how much traffic the websites are going to receive. Your main limitation is the the throughput and bandwidth of the Ethernet port or whatever Wi-Fi solution you are using.

Assuming you can get all 3 websites to play nicely software wise I think in terms of raw performance the Pi will be able to handle things just fine. The Pi 3 packs some reasonable performance CPU wise. If you are finding the CPU is really being hammered then it might be an idea to switch to multiple Pi's.

It's one of those things were you need to try it and see what happens.